# python pyusb import usb.core doesn't work

Tags: python, import, usb, pyusb

I am following the tutorial(http://pyusb.sourceforge.net/docs/1.0/tutorial.html)

I am on windows xp sp3, 
my python version is 2.7 and I downloaded and installed the pyusb-1.0.0-a1.zip

and libusb-win32-bin-1.2.4.0.zip

```
import usb
```

works fine

but

```
import usb.core
```

doesn't working at all

it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\py\usb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from usb import core
  File "D:\py\usb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from usb import core
ImportError: cannot import name core
```

any solution?

thanks!

p.s.
"from usb import core"
this make

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\py\usb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from usb import core
  File "D:\py\usb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from usb import core
ImportError: cannot import name core
```

full source code is here

```
from usb import core
#find device
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1516, idProduct=0x8628)
#found?
if dev is None :
        raise ValueError('device not found')

#set the active config. with no args, the first config will be the active one

dev.set_configuration()

#get an end point instance
ep = usb.util.find_descriptor(
    dev.get_interface_altsetting(), #first interface
    #match the first Out Endpoint
    custom_match = \
        lambda e: \
            usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
            usb.util.ENDPOINT_OUT)
assert ep is not None

while(1):
    ep.write(0x5553424350DDBC880000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000)
    ep.write(0x5553425350ddbc880000000000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\py\usb.py", line 1, in <module>
```

which means it has file `usb.py` in `PATH` earlier (probably in `.` which is `D:\py\` in this case) than path to python modules.

Did you install this module properly? Try rename this `usb.py` file to something else, you'll see if the error becomes "ImportError: No module named usb". Also check Python install path (something like `C:\Python27\`) for usb folder i.e. `<python_path>\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py`.

Comment: i change the directory to desktop, name to usb2.py it says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/kty1104/Desktop/usb2.py", line 3, in <module>
    dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1516, idProduct=0x8628)
NameError: name 'usb' is not defined

Comment: thanks it works fine now is it normal that "import usb" doesn't work but "import usb.core" works?

Comment: Try open interactive Python shell (or even better install and use [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org)) and do: `import usb`, next `help(usb)` (or `usb?` in IPython), find line `FILE` and check if usb module is in given path (shold be a directory called `usb*` with at least __init__.py file and `core.py` file).

Comment: And yet, after 6 years your answer help me understand how to install modules in python. Thanks! :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563098/reference-a-library-in-ironpython-using-visual-studio

Answer (score 12):

Your question says you're using 1.0, but I had the same symptoms as you did, so I'll put this here for future search-engine users.

If you can `import usb` but not `import usb.core` you may be running python-usb 0.x instead of 1.0.

https://github.com/walac/pyusb

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that "D:\py\usb.py" is the name of your py test program.

Unfortunately this make confusion to the py compiler due to the fact that usb is also the name of the module.

Change it in usbtest.py and everything works

Comment: I was going to answer this , Thanks for mentioning it

Answer (score 2):

for **understanding** where python looks to **import your module**, you can run following code :

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

this will show you list of directory names that python searches for your module to import :)